# jquery replacing a number by another issue

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to do a custom metabox in Wordpress with repeatable field including a number before every input (it's for the tracklist of an album) like this :

1. Title (Remove)
2. Title (Remove)
3. etc etc

I have a button "Remove" to delete a field and I need to update to numbers that are superior to the one I replaced.
Every replacement of the numbers (and their IDs ) works fine when I delete a field, except in one situation, when there's more than (of exactly) 10 fiels, the numbers superiors or equal to 10 aren't replacing.

But if a delete the 11th field, the 12th will correctly have it's number replaced by "11".

Here my jquery :

```
jQuery('.repeatable-remove').click(function(){
var splittingNumber = jQuery(this).parent().find('input').attr('id');
var splitNumber = splittingNumber.split('_');
var splittedNumber = splitNumber[2];

jQuery('.album_track').each(function() {

    var albumSplitNumber = this.id.split('_');
    var albumSplittedNumber = albumSplitNumber[2];
    var albumSplittedMinusOne = albumSplittedNumber - 1;

    if (albumSplittedNumber > splittedNumber) {                 

        if (albumSplittedNumber >= 10) {
            jQuery(this).parent().find('.repeatable-autonumber').empty().append(albumSplittedMinusOne+'. ');                    
        }
        else if (splittedNumber < 10) {
            jQuery(this).parent().find('.repeatable-autonumber').empty().append('0'+albumSplittedMinusOne+'. ');
        };

        jQuery(this).attr('id', 'album_track_'+albumSplittedMinusOne);
        jQuery(this).attr('name', 'album_track_'+albumSplittedMinusOne);

    };

})

jQuery(this).parent().remove();
return false;
});
```

For information, I do this with ID fields that are named "album_track_1", "album_track_2", etc...

I really don't understand why there's a problem with the number 10...

EDIT HTML CODE :

```
<ul id="<?php echo $album_tracklist_field['id']; ?>-repeatable" class="custom_repeatable">
<?php
$i = 1;
if (isset($custom["album_track_$i"][0])) {  
    while(!empty($custom["album_track_$i"][0])) {
        ?>
        <li>
            <span class="repeatable-autonumber"><?php if ($i <= 10) { echo '0'.$i.'. '; } else { echo $i.'. '; } ?></span> 
            <input type="text" class="regular-text code album_track" name="album_track_<?php echo $i; ?>" id="album_track_<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $custom["album_track_$i"][0]; ?>"> 
            <span class="repeatable-remove"><?php _e('Remove', 'albums') ?></span>
        </li>
        <?php
        $i++;  
    }  
} else {  
    ?>
    <li>
        <span class="repeatable-autonumber">01. </span>
        <input type="text" class="regular-text code album_track" name="<?php echo 'album_track_' . $i; ?>" id="<?php echo 'album_track_' . $i; ?>" value="" placeholder="<?php _e('Enter the name of the song', 'albums') ?>"> 
        <span class="repeatable-remove"><?php _e('Remove', 'albums') ?></span>
    </li>
    <?php
}  
?>
```

Comment: Put your input fields into list items (LI) in an ordered list (OL) – and you get automatic numbering for free without any additional efforts.

Comment: You're using different variables in your `if()`s - `if (albumSplittedNumber >= 10)` and `else if (splittedNumber < 10)`.  Is that intentional?

Comment: @CBroe it will not solve the problem with IDs (the same as "ordered list")

Comment: What do you need ids for in this kind of form anyways?

Comment: @CBroe To save them in a database.

Comment: That’s still no explanation that makes sense to me. You are trying to gather new user input here, right? So what would any HTML input field id matter for saving this data into the database …?

Comment: @CBoe he's setting `name`s as well, so presumably they're important in the submitted form.  Though I'd have thought names of `album_track[]` would have done something similar.  @Jehan - can you post a sample piece of HTML that your code's working on?  Or better, create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: @Hobo Sorry, I'm not really familiar with jsfiddle...
I've added a sample piece of my html.

But everything is working fine, except when there's one more digit to the number (If a delete the number "6", decrement 10 (and over) is not working, same story if I delete "95", decrement 100 and over isn't working.

The fact is that when there's one more digit to the number to decrement than the deleted number, it's detected as inferior to the deleted number...

Hope I'm clear...

Many thanks

Comment: @Jehan explain "not working" what's the output you're getting? also can't you just use `albumSplittedMinusOne` as the variable in your if and have it as a simple `if/else`?

Comment: @koala_dev "not working" = nothing happens/change.
I don't understand what you mean with `albumSplittedMinusOne`

Comment: that's the variable that holds the updated value, so just do `if(albumSplittedMinusOne >= 10){...}else{...}`

Comment: Yes, it works, and it's more simple indeed, but it does not solve my problem.

If I click to remove the field number "6", the seventh will become "6", the eighth will become "7", etc... But "10" will not become "9" because `if (albumSplittedNumber > splittedNumber)` returns that "10" is inferior to "6", and I don't know why.

Same story if I delete the field "96", "100" will not become "99".

I don't figure the problem, but everytime there's a number with one more digit than the deleted one, it doesn't work.